# win32file.createFile "The System cannot find the specified path"

Tags: python, file, winapi

I'm using `win32file.CreateFile()` to open up "file" that I see in process explorer.
The file in question is (as seen in proc explorer's handles and dlls view) : "\Device\ccSet_{}"

Q1. Can anyone shed light on what is `\Device\<file name>` . I believe these are obviously not files stored on the hard-disks somewhere. Unless I am wrong, what are they ?

Q2. When I try to use the path AS IS, in `win32file.CreateFile()` , it gives me an error "The system cannot find the specified path or file". Where am I going wrong.

Q3. Given an address of the above file object (again from proc explorer), can I read the file without specifying the path ?

the single line of code I am using is :

```
>>> win32file.CreateFile("Device\<filename>",w
in32con.GENERIC_READ|win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ|win32con.FI
LE_SHARE_WRITE,None,win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,0,0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The \Device\XXX names are the internal Windows NT device names.
2. The `\\.\` prefix will access the Win32 device namespace instead of the Win32 file namespace. For instance, to open COM10, you would need to use `\\.\COM10`.
3. The handle is only valid inside the process that opened it.

Comment: "The handle is only valid inside the process that opened it" : is this statement true only when I try to use CreateFile()? I'm asking this because, I am able to duplicate and close the handles in question.

Comment: Indeed, `DuplicateHandle` can be used to workaround that limitation.