# AWS:::sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction"

Tags: amazon-web-services, local, invoke, sam

I have successfully executed sam init and sam build. and my folder structure is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqe3w.png)

While issuing sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" I am getting below error:::handle = win32file.CreateFile(
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Any solution please?

Comment: Maybe add what command are you using? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621671/win32file-createfile-the-system-cannot-find-the-specified-path

Answer (score 0):

Typically this means Docker isn't running. Check that Docker is working.